# Mutating table error when trying to Insert into Table with select

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a problem having mutating table error when inserting data from select in PLSQL.

When im doing insert like this:

```
insert into pozycje_dokumentow
(
        pozycja_dokumentu,
            id_dok,
            stawka_vat,
             miejsce_skladowania,
             jm_kod_jednostka_miary,
             ilosc_jm_sprzedazy,
             ilosc,
             indeks_czesci
)
values(
        1014,
        1882706,
        23,
        4709,
        'L15',
        388.33,
        386.713,
        26539
);
```

It all works good, but when i try to do it in this way:

```
insert into pozycje_dokumentow
(
        pozycja_dokumentu,
            id_dok,
            stawka_vat,
             miejsce_skladowania,
             jm_kod_jednostka_miary,
             ilosc_jm_sprzedazy,
             ilosc,
             indeks_czesci
)
Select
        1014,
        1882706,
        23,
        4709,
        'L4',
        388.33,
        386.713,
        26539
from dual
```

I get an error in before_insert trigger on table pozycje_dokumentow:
ORA-20298: ORA-04091: ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

What is the diffrence in those two querys?

Trigger's body that is generating error, only when doing insert select from the same table that trigger is created:

```
select nvl(max(lp),0) + 1
    into :new.lp
    from pozycje_dokumentow
   where id_dok = :new.id_dok
   group by id_dok;
```

Comment: This is caused by some badly written trigger. You need to **[edit]** your question and add the full PL/SQL code of the (insert) trigger

Comment: and why when i use values, it works perfectly ?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the trigger code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't say that it is `insert` that makes the difference. If you run the first `insert` (which "works OK") twice, you'd - I believe - get the same error.

It is probably because trigger code selects from the `pozycje_dokumentow`, the same table that is affected by `insert` so it is *mutating*.

I guess you'll have to rewrite the trigger (or change the way you're doing the whole thing).

---

A sequence approach which will, hopefully, fix your problems.

```
create sequence seqa;

create or replace trigger trg_bi_podok 
  before insert on pozycje_dokumentow
  for each row
begin
  :new.id := seqa.nextval;
end;
```

---

As of "unique PK per document": there is a  way to do that. Here's a sample code you might use (i.e. adjust to your situation) - it requires an autonomous transaction function which locks the table that contains PK values, fetches the next PK number and releases the table.

```
CREATE TABLE EVIDENCIJA_BROJ
(
  DP        NUMBER(4)                           NOT NULL,
  REDNI_BR  NUMBER                              NOT NULL,
  WHAT      VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  GODINA    NUMBER(4)
);

   FUNCTION f_get_evidencija_broj (par_dp       IN NUMBER,
                                   par_what     IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'EVID',
                                   par_godina   IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      l_redni_br   evidencija_broj.redni_br%TYPE;
   BEGIN
          SELECT b.redni_br + 1
            INTO l_redni_br
            FROM evidencija_broj b
           WHERE     b.dp = par_dp
                 AND (   b.godina = par_godina
                      OR par_godina IS NULL)
                 AND b.what = par_what
      FOR UPDATE OF b.redni_br;

      UPDATE evidencija_broj b
         SET b.redni_br = l_redni_br
       WHERE     b.dp = par_dp
             AND b.what = par_what
             AND (   b.godina = par_godina
                  OR par_godina IS NULL);

      COMMIT;
      RETURN (l_redni_br);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
      THEN
         LOCK TABLE evidencija_broj IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

         INSERT INTO evidencija_broj (dp,
                                      godina,
                                      what,
                                      redni_br)
              VALUES (par_dp,
                      par_godina,
                      par_what,
                      1);

         COMMIT;
         RETURN (1);
   END f_get_evidencija_broj;
```

Comment: nah, im not getting this error when doing it for the second time, i just get some other constraint error.
Select from dual returning only 1 row, so its the same quantity of rows being inserted.

Comment: What happens if you temporarily disable that "some other constraint" and then run the first INSERT twice? Maybe that constraint fails first (so trigger isn't executed yet).

Comment: impossible, its connected with primary key in this table :(

Comment: As I told you - trigger is selecting from the same table that is affected by INSERT and, therefore, *mutates*. Nonetheless: "MAX + 1" is wrong, you should avoid it unless it is strictly a single-user environment. Otherwise, it'll fail sooner or later because two (or more) users will fetch the same value and primary key constraint will be violated. Switch to a **sequence** and all your problems will be gone (kind of ...)

Comment: problem with sequence is, that i have that id, per each document, and it should start always from 1 for each new document

Comment: but i deleted this select, and it worked! thanks :) i will try to solve it soon in other way.

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited my answer by adding code which might help you fix it - create a table which will hold PK values, along with a function that returns unique numbers. I just copy/pasted my function, you'll have to adjust it a little bit. Good luck!

Comment: You are totally right, autonomous transaction should do the job here.
Thanks for your replys, have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because the first version does a single-row `INSERT` and the second one does a multi-row `INSERT` (since you're using a `SELECT` to generate the values - from Oracle's point of view, it's totally irrelevant how many rows your `SELECT` returns. It only matters that Oracle cannot guarantee that your `SELECT` returns only one row).

I'd guess that you have a `BEFORE INSERT` row-level trigger - that's AFAIK the only case where there's a difference between multi-row `INSERT` and single-row `INSERT`, see [Database journal article on mutating table error](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3329121/The-Mutation-error-in-Oracle-Database-Triggers.htm) for details.

As @Littlefoot has pointed out in their answer - you need to rewrite the trigger / switch to a compound trigger, or (better yet) move your application logic out of the trigger altogether.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how oracle treats insert into select.